# fastapi fastapi-users with Database adapter for SQLModel users table is not created

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi, sqlmodel

I was trying to use [fastapi users](https://github.com/fastapi-users/fastapi-users) package to quickly Add a registration and authentication system to my FastAPI project which uses the PostgreSQL database. I am using `asyncio` to be able to create asynchronous functions.

In the beginning, I used only sqlAlchemy and I have tried their example [here](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/configuration/full-example/). And I added those line of codes to my app/app.py to create the database at the starting of the server. and everything worked like a charm. the table users was created on my database.

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    await create_db_and_tables()
```

Since I am using SQLModel I added [FastAPI Users - Database adapter for SQLModel](https://github.com/fastapi-users/fastapi-users-db-sqlmodel) to my virtual en packages. And I added those lines to `fastapi_users/db/__init__.py` to be able to use the SQL model database.

```py
try:
    from fastapi_users_db_sqlmodel import (  # noqa: F401
        SQLModelBaseOAuthAccount,
        SQLModelBaseUserDB,
        SQLModelUserDatabase,
    )
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    pass
```

I have also modified `app/users.py`, to use `SQLModelUserDatabase` instead of sqlAchemy one.

```py
async def get_user_manager(user_db: SQLModelUserDatabase = Depends(get_user_db)):
    yield UserManager(user_db)
```

and the `app/dp.py` to use `SQLModelUserDatabase`, `SQLModelBaseUserDB`, here is the full code of `app/db.py`

```py
import os
from typing import AsyncGenerator

from fastapi import Depends
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from fastapi_users.db import SQLModelUserDatabase, SQLModelBaseUserDB
from sqlmodel import SQLModel


from app.models import UserDB

DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")


engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)

async_session_maker = sessionmaker(
    engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


async def create_db_and_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)


async def get_async_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(
        engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False
    )
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


async def get_user_db(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    yield SQLModelUserDatabase(UserDB, session, SQLModelBaseUserDB)
```

Once I run the code, the table is not created at all. I wonder what could be the issue. I could not understand. Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Does `UserDB` inherit from the example `User` class defined in the `app/db.py` file from [full example](https://fastapi-users.github.io/fastapi-users/10.2/configuration/full-example/)? (Which then inherits from `SQLAlchemyBaseUserTableUUID`)

Comment: Check my answer and the provided link please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time I posted this question that was the answer I received from one of the maintainer of `fastapi-users` that made me switch to `sqlAlchemy` that time, actually I do not know if they officially released sqlModel DB adapter or not

> My guess is that you didn't change the `UserDB` model so that it inherits from the `SQLModelBaseUserDB` one. It's necessary in order to let `SQLModel` detect all your models and create them.

> You can have an idea of what it should look like in `fastapi-users-db-sqlmodel` tests: https://github.com/fastapi-users/fastapi-users-db-sqlmodel/blob/3a46b80399f129aa07a834a1b40bf49d08c37be1/tests/conftest.py#L25-L27

> > Bear in mind though that we didn't **officially release** this DB adapter; as they are some problems with `SQLModel` regarding `UUID` (tiangolo/sqlmodel#25). So you'll probably run into issues.

and here is the GitHub link of the issue: https://github.com/fastapi-users/fastapi-users/discussions/861

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but managed to make it work by making a couple changes

The changes that I needed to make (code is based on the full example in the documentation):

1. In models.py, make `UserDB` inherit from `SQLModelBaseUserDB, User`, and add `table=True` for sqlmodel to create the table:

```
    class UserDB(SQLModelBaseUserDB, User, table=True):
        pass
```

It's important that `SQLModelBaseUserDB` is inherited from first, because otherwise `User.id` trumps `SQLModelBaseUserDB.id` and sqlmodel cannot find `primary_key` column

2. Use `SQLModelUserDatabaseAsync` in `get_user_db`, like this (as far as I understand, you don't need to pass in SQLModelBaseUserDB in SQLModelUserDatabase. The third argument is for oauth account model):

```
async def get_user_db(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    yield SQLModelUserDatabaseAsync(UserDB, session)
```

Comment: I am getting an exception `type object 'User' has no attribute '__config__'` occurring when `app.database.User` is being imported. Is it correct to assume `class User(SQLAlchemyBaseUserTableUUID, Base)` here?  Thanks.